# display nested array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I am using cakePHP 2.2 and wondering how I can output information within this nest array.

I am trying to display the data within [Job] => Array & [Children] => Array. I have provided my current cakePHP code which may assist.

**Array output**

```
[4] => Array
    (
        [Job] => Array
            (
                [id] => 20
                [parent_id] => 0
                [rght] => 6
                [lft] => 1
                [client_id] => tasd
                [contact] => asdf
                [email] => sdf
                [address] => 
                [lat] => 
                [long] => 
                [user_id] => 1
                [request_type_id] => Electrical
                [date_start] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                [date_end] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                [date_complete] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                [date_closed] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                [status] => open
                [brief_desc] => aasdf
                [desc] => asdfasdf
                [cost_est] => 3434.00
                [cost_actual] => 
                [created] => 2011-12-18 20:39:24
                [modified] => 2011-12-18 20:39:24
            )


        [Children] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 21
                        [parent_id] => 20
                        [rght] => 3
                        [lft] => 2
                        [client_id] => TEST3333
                        [brief_desc] => testsdf
                        [desc] => asdfasdfasdf
                        [cost_est] => 3434.00
                        [cost_actual] => 
                        [created] => 2011-12-18 20:42:13
                        [modified] => 2011-12-18 20:42:13
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 22
                        [parent_id] => 20
                        [rght] => 5
                        [lft] => 4
                        [client_id] => TEST666666    
                        [brief_desc] => testsdf
                        [desc] => asdfasdfasdf
                        [cost_est] => 3434.00
                        [cost_actual] => 
                        [created] => 2011-12-18 20:42:43
                        [modified] => 2011-12-18 20:42:43
                    )
```

Current cakePHP code:

```
  <?php

foreach ($jobs as $job): ?>

  <li><a href="/jobs/view/<?php echo h($job['Job']['id']); ?>">
  <h3>J<?php echo h($job['Job']['id']); ?> - <?php echo h($job['Job']['brief_desc']); ?     ></h3>
  <p><?php echo h($job['Job']['desc']); ?></p>
  <a href="/jobs/edit/<?php echo h($job['Job']['id']); ?>"></a>     

  </a>

  <?php




  ?>
  </li>



<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: could you be clear, what are you trying to achieve..?

Comment: Sorry I have updated my post to make it more clear.

Comment: is that foreach loop not working..?

Comment: That is working perfect at displaying data from the [Job], I can't get it from [Children]

Comment: Thanks Sudhir, I tried something similar to this but it didn't work. All is good now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
foreach($jobs as $job) {
  echo $job['Job']['id'];
  foreach($job['Children'] as $child) {
     echo $child['id'];
  }
}
```

Comment: If it is a recursive structure that can have multiple levels of nesting, then you might want to look into the [TreeHelper](https://www.dereuromark.de/2013/02/17/cakephp-and-tree-structures/) and the options around this.

Answer (score 0):

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category_id] => 2
            [category_name] => Home
            [parent_id] => 
        )

```
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [category_id] => 3
        [category_name] => Clothing
        [parent_id] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [category_id] => 8
                        [category_name] => dreass
                        [parent_id] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [category_id] => 10
                                        [category_name] => new
                                        [parent_id] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [category_id] => 11
                                                        [category_name] => nnnn
                                                        [parent_id] => 
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [category_id] => 9
                        [category_name] => apint
                        [parent_id] => 
                    )

                [2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [category_id] => 13
                        [category_name] => T-shirt
                        [parent_id] => 
                    )

            )

    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [category_id] => 4
        [category_name] => Beauty
        [parent_id] => 
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [category_id] => 5
        [category_name] => Gift Cards 
        [parent_id] => 
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [category_id] => 6
        [category_name] => Toys
        [parent_id] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [category_id] => 12
                        [category_name] => toy1
                        [parent_id] => 
                    )

            )

    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [category_id] => 7
        [category_name] => Sports
        [parent_id] => 
    )
```

)

Comment: You will be of even more help if you explain you answer. See here for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer